# How to pass object which contain Bitmap to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bitmap, parcelable

so I am kind of new in Android Developing, I was trying to make a Sign-up Activity (`UserPrivateInfoSignUpActivity.java`) that load a picture (Bitmap) and create a `UserPersona` Object that I want to pass into another Activity (`UserGeneralDataSignUpActivity`).

I did a research for solutions and somehow I am still unable to pass the Bitmap image although it is already `implements Parcelable`.

Any suggestions?
Here is my code (without getters & setters)

**PersonaUser.java:**

```
public class PersonaUser implements Parcelable{

private String puName;
private String puEmailAddress;
private String puCountry;
private String puCity;
private int puAge;
private Bitmap puImage;

public PersonaUser(String puName, String puEmailAddress, String puCountry, String puCity,
                   int puAge, Bitmap puImage){
    this.puName = puName;
    this.puEmailAddress = puEmailAddress;
    this.puCountry = puCountry;
    this.puCity = puCity;
    this.puAge = puAge;
    this.puImage = puImage;
}

//Constructor using parcel
public PersonaUser(Parcel in) {
    this.puName = in.readString();
    this.puEmailAddress = in.readString();
    this.puCountry = in.readString();
    this.puCity = in.readString();
    this.puAge = in.readInt();
    this.puImage = (Bitmap) in.readValue(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(puName);
    parcel.writeString(puEmailAddress);
    parcel.writeString(puCountry);
    parcel.writeString(puCity);
    parcel.writeInt(puAge);
    parcel.writeValue(puImage);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<PersonaUser> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<PersonaUser>() {
    @Override
    public PersonaUser createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new PersonaUser(in);  //using parcelable constructor
    }

    @Override
    public PersonaUser[] newArray(int i) {
        return new PersonaUser[i];
    }
};


}
```

**UserPrivateInfoSignUpActivity.java:**

```
public class UserPrivateInfoSignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int IMAGES_FROM_GALLERY = 1;
Button nextActivityButton, pickImageButton;
Bitmap puImageBitmap;
PersonaUser npUser;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_private_info_sign_up);

    nextActivityButton = findViewById(R.id.next_activity);
    pickImageButton = findViewById(R.id.pick_image);

    addImage();
    nextActivity();
}


//Get image from gallery
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    puImageBitmap = null;
    //Detects request codes
    if (requestCode == IMAGES_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try {
            puImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(puImageBitmap);
}

// next Activity
public void nextActivity(){
    nextActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(UserPrivateInfoSignUpActivity.this,
                    UserGeneralDataSignUpActivity.class);
            npUser = new PersonaUser("example", "example","example","example",21,puImageBitmap);
            i.putExtra("user" , npUser);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

//add Image method
public void addImage(){
    pickImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, IMAGES_FROM_GALLERY);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**UserGeneralDataSignUpActivity.java** (where I want to retrieve the user object)

```
public class UserGeneralDataSignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_general_data_sign_up);


    Intent i = getIntent();
    ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.show); //where I want to display image
    PersonaUser pu = i.getParcelableExtra("user");
    iv.setImageBitmap(pu.getPuImage()); //PersonaUser method (returns Bitmap)

}
```

It successfully move to the next Activty, though each time I load a picture and afterwards try moving to the next Activity my app crashes.

[Here I add the LogCat (after adding image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Syp7.png)

```
    04-15 10:40:09.720 20654-20654/com.rarely1gmail.personas E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 3687084)
04-15 10:40:09.721 20654-20654/com.rarely1gmail.personas D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-15 10:40:09.725 20654-20654/com.rarely1gmail.personas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.rarely1gmail.personas, PID: 20654
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1618)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
                                                                               at com.rarely1gmail.personas.UserPrivateInfoSignUpActivity$1.onClick(UserPrivateInfoSignUpActivity.java:74)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                            Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 3687084 bytes
                                                                               at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:764)
                                                                               at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4351)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1611)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487) 
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54) 
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445) 
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774) 
                                                                               at com.rarely1gmail.personas.UserPrivateInfoSignUpActivity$1.onClick(UserPrivateInfoSignUpActivity.java:74) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Thanks.

Comment: share error logcat..

Comment: edited with logcat

Comment: Please include error messages in the question, not as an external link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not a great idea to pass Bitmap between two activities. You would get `TransactionTooLargeException` when you attempt to do so. Maximum limit for transaction data is around 1MB and Bitmap could easily overshoot it. This could lead to crash.

You can just use the URI that you are getting in `onActivityResult()` via following code:

`Uri selectedImage = data.getData();`

Pass this URI between the activities. You can then load image using the URI on-demand rather than transfering whole Bitmap object.

@SabaJafarzade Thank you pointing out, to reuse the Uri.

Comment: You are getting exactly the same error: `TransactionTooLargeException`.

Read your error log carefully

Comment: Does he need to write it to the file or he can use the same URI that he get from onActivityResult? 
Maybe try to save that URI into your object and pass it to the next activity

Comment: @SabaJafarzadeh good point. He can also just pass the URI. That will do. I will update my answer.