# passing byte Array image into next Activity

Tags: android, layout

My app consist Image Capture Face Recognition what i need to implement is converting the byte Array image into bitmap , and pass the bitmap to next Activity, The next Activity will receive the bitmap and show it in an image-view , than convert the bitmap into base 64.

I Don't know how to implement above task into my existing codes.
So when image is captured it shows, once click to save button pass the image to next activity and again convert the bitmap into base64.

**FaceTrackerAcivity.java**

```
public final class FaceTrackerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "FaceTracker";

private CameraSource mCameraSource = null;

private CameraSourcePreview mPreview;
private GraphicOverlay mGraphicOverlay;
private ImageView btnCapture;
private ImageView btnChangeCamera;
private ImageView btnCancel;
private ImageView btnSave;
private FrameLayout frmResult;
private ImageView imgPicture;


Bitmap bmp;
private static final int RC_HANDLE_GMS = 9001;
// permission request codes need to be < 256
private static final int RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM = 2;
private static final int RC_HANDLE_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERM = 3;
private int cameraId = CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;

Intent x;

//==============================================================================================
// Activity Methods
//==============================================================================================

/**
 * Initializes the UI and initiates the creation of a face detector.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mPreview = (CameraSourcePreview) findViewById(R.id.preview);
    mGraphicOverlay = (GraphicOverlay) findViewById(R.id.faceOverlay);
    btnCapture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_capture);
    btnChangeCamera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_change_camera);
    btnCancel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    btnSave = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    frmResult = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frm_capture_result);
    imgPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_capture_result);

    boolean hasPermissionCamera = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    if (!hasPermissionCamera) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM);
    } else {
        boolean hasPermissionWriteStorage = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        if (!hasPermissionWriteStorage) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, RC_HANDLE_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERM);
        } else {
            createCameraSource(cameraId);
        }
    }


    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnChangeCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
}


private void createCameraSource(int cameraId) {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .build();

    detector.setProcessor(
            new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(new GraphicFaceTrackerFactory())
                    .build());

    if (!detector.isOperational()) {

        Log.w(TAG, "Face detector dependencies are not yet available.");
    }

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(metrics.heightPixels, metrics.widthPixels)
            .setFacing(cameraId)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .setRequestedFps(30.0f)
            .build();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    startCameraSource();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mPreview.stop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mCameraSource != null) {
        mCameraSource.release();
    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
            break;
        }
        case RC_HANDLE_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERM: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}


private void startCameraSource() {

    // check that the device has play services available.
    int code = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(
            getApplicationContext());
    if (code != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Dialog dlg = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, code, RC_HANDLE_GMS);
        dlg.show();
    }

    if (mCameraSource != null) {
        try {
            mPreview.start(mCameraSource, mGraphicOverlay);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to start camera source.", e);
            mCameraSource.release();
            mCameraSource = null;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    if (id == R.id.btn_capture) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mCameraSource.takePicture(null, new CameraSource.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] bytes) {
                int orientation = Exif.getOrientation(bytes);


                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 2;
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, options);



                switch (orientation) {
                    case 90:
                        bmp = Utils.rotateImage(bmp, 90);
                        break;
                    case 180:
                        bmp = Utils.rotateImage(bmp, 180);
                        break;
                    case 270:
                        bmp = Utils.rotateImage(bmp, 270);
                        break;
                }

                if (cameraId == CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                    bmp = Utils.flip(bmp, Constants.FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
                }

                if (bmp != null) {
                    frmResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imgPicture.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            frmResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
                    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            SavePhotoTask savePhotoTask = new SavePhotoTask();
                            savePhotoTask.execute(bytes);


                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    } else if (id == R.id.btn_change_camera) {
        mCameraSource.release();
        mCameraSource = null;
        cameraId = cameraId == CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK ? CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT : CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
        createCameraSource(cameraId);
        startCameraSource();
    }
}


private class GraphicFaceTrackerFactory implements MultiProcessor.Factory<Face> {
    @Override
    public Tracker<Face> create(Face face) {
        return new GraphicFaceTracker(mGraphicOverlay);
    }
}


private class GraphicFaceTracker extends Tracker<Face> {
    private GraphicOverlay mOverlay;
    private FaceGraphic mFaceGraphic;

    GraphicFaceTracker(GraphicOverlay overlay) {
        mOverlay = overlay;
        mFaceGraphic = new FaceGraphic(overlay);
    }


    @Override
    public void onNewItem(int faceId, Face item) {
        mFaceGraphic.setId(faceId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(FaceDetector.Detections<Face> detectionResults, Face face) {
        mOverlay.add(mFaceGraphic);
        mFaceGraphic.updateFace(face);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMissing(FaceDetector.Detections<Face> detectionResults) {
        mOverlay.remove(mFaceGraphic);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDone() {
        mOverlay.remove(mFaceGraphic);
    }
}

class SavePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "TRACKER_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        try {
            File photo = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
            fos.write(data[0]);
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}}
```

**NEXT.java**

```
public class NEXT extends AppCompatActivity {


ImageView y;
Intent intent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.next);

    y = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);

    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("key");
    y.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass object which contain Bitmap to another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840916/how-to-pass-object-which-contain-bitmap-to-another-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Putin large data (>1Mo) can produce `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException`, ref :

> The Binder transaction buffer has a **limited fixed size, currently
>   1Mb**, which is shared by all transactions in progress for the
>   process. Consequently this exception can be thrown when there are many
>   transactions in progress even when most of the individual transactions
>   are of moderate size.

The best way is to create a class and put your image into it, you can then access to it from any activity

Comment: but i just to implement this to my codes, my app is all bout passing one image only.

Comment: If you save the image in the first activity, then you can use and intent to pass the URI/Path to the secend activity, if not you have to create a class to wrap your image and get it in the other activity